# Changing values based off variables in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

I'm trying to make a text go from '0' when a box hasn't been clicked to '1' when it has been clicked. However, the variable  I have sets the text as '0' before it is clicked, and so when the box is clicked and the variable is changed, the text isn't changed. Here's the code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
height = 500
width = 500
canvas = Canvas(width=width, height=height)
root.title = "Test"


def click(event):
    item = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    tags = canvas.gettags(item)

    if tags[0] == 'rect1':
        canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="blue")
        click.value = '1'


click.value = '0'

text = click.value


canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 400, 400, tags='rect1', fill='white')

canvas.create_text(200, 300, font='Times 50', text=text, anchor=E)


canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)
canvas.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set a variable and expect the canvas to change. You need to call `itemconfigure` on the text object to change the text in the exact same way that you call `itemconfigure` on the rectangle to change the color.